# What is your favourite strategy for tackling reports in ruby projects?

Tags: ruby, reporting, report

Recently, a customer required a complex report with multiple transformations on a large dataset.

I employed Ruport - which is an excellent choice for quick and dirty reporting. However, after a few trials I realized that ruport nested groupings and normalized data don't go together. The choices that now remained included:

1. Denormalize data (possibly in a view
   with nightly updates) + perform some
   formatting in Ruby
2. Use a completely different toolkit
       (JasperReports?)

I dread both possibilities. Does anyone have a better idea (ideally restricting the scope of work to ruby alone)?

Answer (score 1):

[Munger](http://github.com/schacon/munger/tree/master) is aimed to be an alternative to Ruport so it maybe worth looking at.